# Inflate custom android widget

Tags: java, android, custom-component

I know there are dozens similar post, but it looks to me everything is correct here:

The custom widget:

```
public class DoubleTextItem extends LinearLayout {

private TextView txtMain;
private TextView txtDescription;

public DoubleTextItem(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public DoubleTextItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.widget_double_text_item, this);
    setupViewItems();
}

private void setupViewItems() {
    txtMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
    txtDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDecription);
}
public void setDescription(String text) {
    txtDescription.setText(text);
}
}
```

The custom widget layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDecription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ANd here inside an activity function i get a casting error,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
DoubleTextItem item = (DoubleTextItem) inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_double_text_item, layout);              
item.setText(som-txt);
item.setDescription("#"+athlete.getString("position"));
```

Comment: What is `othertxt` and where and how is it set?

Comment: It's hard to help your when you make up code: `item.setText(som-txt);` unless you are seeing an compile time error since `-` is a mathematical operation...

Comment: sometxt is just String sometxt = "hello";
no compile time errors. no warnings.
just on execution when its up to that method. crash, exit, and huge stack ending with a ClassCastException : LinearLayout in first case.nvm second case. aparently no error there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the root View is a LinearLayout but you try to cast it your custom class:

```
DoubleTextItem item = (DoubleTextItem) inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_double_text_item, layout);
```

The standard advice is:

> All DoubleTextItems are LinearLayouts, but not all LinearLayouts are DoubleTextItems.

Meaning you cannot downcast objects from a LinearLayout to a DoubleTextItem, there are too many assumptions and Java won't let you do it.

If you want a DoubleTextItem in your layout you need to use:

```
<your.package.name.DoubleTextItem 
    ... />
```

(Also, calling inflate inside `onFinishInflate()` seems a little silly especially since you don't save the inflated item... If you want to inflate a different layout, don't inflate the first one.)

---

Overall it looks like you are trying to recreate the now deprecated [TwoLineListItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.html), perhaps you can learn some pointers from it's [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.java#TwoLineListItem) (or just use the TwoLineListItem.)

Comment: Yep 3rd day learning and architecture... loks like i didnt get something. ill try and check

Comment: There's something i can't grasp, i swapped the LinearLayout with package.DoubleTextItem but it has another error while inflating the xml now.
And what do you mean with onFinishInflate is silly.. ? 
Yes i am trying to do something like TwoLineListItem.
I am trying to find a good tutorial on this android aspect, but i dont find any. i hate these API, most of the stuff i find is deprecated, and hatever is on dev.andr is for 1% marketshare..

Comment: Ok, click ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14801580/edit) underneath your question to post your new XML and LogCat errors, so I can see what is happening. Also I believe the `inflate()` command in `onFinishInflate()` is unnecessary because that is the same layout that you already inflated and you don't save it, so it does nothing...

Comment: Finally i understood the issue. Not here, but this answer helped me addressing to the right view. thanks